# How to SELECT DEFAULT value of a field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I can't seem to find or write a sqlquery that SELECTS the DEFAULT VALUE

(and I don't think I can generate it in phpmyadmin for me to copy)

I tried to SELECT it as if it was a record but to no avail...

```
 $defaultValue_find = mysql_query(
         "SELECT $group FROM grouptable WHERE $group='DEFAULT'")  
      or die("Query failed:".mysql_error());
 $defaultValue_fetch = mysql_fetch_row($defaultValue_find);
 $defaultValue = $defaultValue_fetch[0];
 echo $defaultValue;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
"SELECT $group FROM grouptable WHERE $group=DEFAULT( $group ) "
```

Or I think better:

```
"SELECT DEFAULT( $group ) FROM grouptable LIMIT 1 "
```

---

**Update - correction**

As @Jeff Caron pointed, the above will only work if there is at least 1 row in `grouptable`. If you want the result even if the grouptable has no rows, you can use this:

```
"SELECT DEFAULT( $group ) 
 FROM (SELECT 1) AS dummy
   LEFT JOIN grouptable 
     ON True
 LIMIT 1 ;"
```

Comment: I used the second one. Perfect thanks. One note is, of course, ('group') should read ($group) - solely in relation to the way i framed the question - anyways, thanks and accepted!

Comment: @Adam: you are right. If `$group` is a column, yes. I thought for a moment that it might be a value of a column, edited now.

Comment: This will only works if there is at least 1 result. As far as I know, the only way to always get the default value of a column is with something like that: 
SELECT COLUMN_DEFAULT FROM information_schema.columns WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_database_name' AND TABLE_NAME = 'your_table_name' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'your_column_name';

Answer (score 0):

Get the default values of `all` fields in `mytable` in the associative array `$res`:

```
// MySQL v.5.7+
$res = [];
$sql = "SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `mytable`";
foreach ($PDO->query( $sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) as $row) {
    $res[$row['Field']] = $row['Default'] ;
}
print_r($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the default column of any table, and in fact lots of interesting information about it, by looking at the [**`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema.html) tables. As the documentation states...

> INFORMATION_SCHEMA provides access to database metadata, information about the MySQL server such as the name of a database or table, the data type of a column, or access privileges. (Source: **[MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual / `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` Tables / Introduction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-introduction.html)**.)

So, to get the column default, just `SELECT COLUMN_DEFAULT`, like...

```
SELECT COLUMN_DEFAULT
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YourSchema'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'YourTable' AND 
COLUMN_NAME = 'YourField';
```

You can then just wrap this into a subquery, `SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE YourField = (queryabove)`.  This lets you make a much more customizable, default-based list in your MySQL query.