# Can I get back default values for column names in a MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I can get the column names for a table but is there a way to retrieve the default data value for each column?

Here is what I'm using to get the tables column names:

```
$q = $dbh->query("DESCRIBE tablename"); 
$table_fields = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

print_r($table_fields);
```

This prints an array of column names, but I'm trying to get the default data value for each column name also.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266771/how-to-select-default-value-of-a-field

Answer (score 13):

Another option is to go to the data dictionary and find the value in `Information_Schema.Columns`. This allows you to limit results to a single column.

```
$query = <<< endsql
 SELECT Column_Default
  FROM Information_Schema.Columns
  WHERE Table_Schema = '$yourSchema'
    AND Table_Name = '$yourTableName'
    AND Column_Name = '$yourColumnName'
endsql;
```

Comment: In my case, i needed the `extra` column to see if the field was auto_increment, but this answer pointed the way

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
$query = "SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM tableName";
// ...
```

Column `Default`.

I hope I helped.

Answer (score -2):

Just give an index after your FETCH_COLUMN. I didn't try your code but based on [DESCRIBE manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/explain.html) it will return 6 description columns. So if you have read [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) you may got the solution. I have read them and I think just by adding 4th index on your code like below will be your solution.

```
$table_fields = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN,4);
```