# How to get a column's default value using Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-artisan

I am building a custom artisan command that needs to be able to access the database's default values for certain columns. I cannot use the attributes array. So instead I need another way.

I have tried to use `Schema`. I have been able to get the table `DB::table($table)` and the column names `Schema::getColumnListings($table)` but not the default values.

Is there some other way to get the default values?

Comment: I don't think there's a command to do it, but [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266771/how-to-select-default-value-of-a-field) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915445/can-i-get-back-default-values-for-column-names-in-a-mysql-table) might help you create your own method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Laravel Schema Builder only returns column names by design. But you can use the same approach Laravel uses internally by executing a database statement:

```
$results = DB::select('
    select column_default 
    from information_schema.columns 
    where 
        table_schema = ? 
        and table_name = ?
', [$database, $table]);

// Flatten the results to get an array of the default values
$defaults = collect($results)->pluck('column_default'))
```

The above example works for a MySQL database, but you can see the approaches for other databases in the `Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars` namespace of the Laravel source code by searching for the method `compileColumnListing`.

Answer (score 2):

In **Laravel 5+ (including 6 and 7)**, you can get the db table column metadata (ie type, default value etc) in the following way:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
```

For all columns:

```
$columns = Schema::getConnection()->getDoctrineSchemaManager()->listTableColumns('table_name');
```

For a single column:

```
$column = Schema::getConnection()->getDoctrineColumn('table_name'', 'column_name');
```

`getDoctrineSchemaManager` method returns a array of `\Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Column` Class Instances. By using this you can get everything about a db table column.

`getDoctrineColumn` method returns the instance of `\Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Column` class.

Couple of methods from `\Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Column` class:

```
$column->getName();
$column->getNotnull(); // returns true/false
$column->getDefault(); 
$column->getType(); 
$column->getLength();
```