# SELECT DEFAULT returns NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I want to return two defaults column values even if the table has no records. I'm using the following query (thanks to [How to SELECT DEFAULT value of a field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8266834/466153)):

```
SELECT DEFAULT(membership_credits) AS membership_credits,
       DEFAULT(product_credits) AS product_credits
FROM (SELECT 1) AS dummy LEFT JOIN Users ON True LIMIT 1
```

But instead of the default values, I'm getting NULL:

```
membership_credits  product_credits
              NULL             NULL
```

What's the problem?

EDIT:

Adding the table schema as suggested in a comment:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
  user_id BIGINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_login VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  user_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  user_email VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  user_telephone VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  user_password VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  user_address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  user_postal_code VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  user_district VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  user_country VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  user_tax_number VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  user_billing_email VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
  company_description TEXT,
  company_history TEXT,
  company_products TEXT,
  public_contact BINARY(1) NOT NULL,
  user_active BINARY(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  user_key VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  user_registered TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  unread_messages INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0,
  membership_credits INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  product_credits INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE INNODB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: You will probably need to post your table schema

Comment: Do those columns have a default value?

Comment: make sure you have set default values for columns

Comment: Columns have default values. I edited the question with the schema.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it in my local 5.5 server.

Comment: I have `Server version: 5.6.11-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)` and it returns `NULL` on empty tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on if your columns allow `NULL` or not.

If `NULL` allow, a query like the following will be useful, so the table does not have records:

```sql
SELECT
  DEFAULT(`membership_credits`) `membership_credits`,
  DEFAULT(`product_credits`) `product_credits`
FROM (SELECT 1) `dummy`
  LEFT JOIN `users` ON TRUE
LIMIT 1;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15c2d4/4)</kbd>

If not allow `NULL`, and the table has no record, you will get a `NULL` to the query above. In this case would require a query like:

```sql
SELECT
  DEFAULT(`membership_credits`) `membership_credits`,
  DEFAULT(`product_credits`) `product_credits`
FROM (SELECT *, COUNT(0)
    FROM `users`) `users`;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2038a/4)</kbd>

**UPDATE**

Be careful in MySQL >= 5.6 does not operate in the same way and NULL values ​​are obtained.

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91471/1)</kbd>

Comment: The allowing of `NULL` or not really makes sense. I've only tested your second query. It works! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you use following query to create table

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `user_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_login` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    `user_name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `user_email` VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
    `user_telephone` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `user_password` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    `user_address` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `user_postal_code` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `user_district` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `user_country` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `user_tax_number` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `user_billing_email` VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
    `company_description` TEXT NULL,
    `company_history` TEXT NULL,
    `company_products` TEXT NULL,
    `public_contact` BINARY(1) NOT NULL,
    `user_active` BINARY(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `user_key` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `user_registered` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `unread_messages` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `membership_credits` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `product_credits` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `user_login` (`user_login`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `user_email` (`user_email`)
)
```

And use below query to get default values

```
            SELECT if(DEFAULT(membership_credits) is null,0,
DEFAULT(membership_credits))AS membership_credits,if(DEFAULT(product_credits)
 is null,0,DEFAULT(product_credits) )AS product_credits FROM
 (SELECT 1) AS dummy LEFT JOIN Users ON True LIMIT 1
```

You must note that in the above create query `membership_credits` and `product_credits` modified to allow null

Comment: Did you check if the referred `select default ...` works on your proposition?

Comment: @Ravinder output is 0

Comment: Questions: 1. Is the table empty? 2. If yes, what is the default `ENGINE`? 3. If `INNODB`, what version of `MySQL`?

Comment: @Ravinder - table is empty , ENGINE=InnoDB and mysql  version - 5.1.46

Comment: Hmm ... I have `Server version: 5.6.11-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)` and returns `NULL` on empty table. !!!

Comment: @Ravinder - modified my answer, check now

Comment: Well, modified answer is an *other way around*! What wondered is [*Why not this output !?*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8266834/767881)

Comment: Cool? Why not direct call to `default( col )` resulting the defined `DEFAULT 0` ...? is the point here ...

Comment: Your query solves the problem changing the schema. But I'm accepting wchiquito's answer because he also presents a query that works without the modifying the schema.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Query

```
SELECT COLUMN_DEFAULT FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_database_name' AND 
TABLE_NAME = 'your_table_name' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'your_column_name';
```

In Your case

```
SELECT COLUMN_DEFAULT FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test' AND
TABLE_NAME = 'users' AND 
COLUMN_NAME in ('membership_credits','product_credits');
```

Comment: This is an alternative but from what I've tested, is slower than the approach I present in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use below query :

> SELECT 
>       IF(COUNT(user_id) = 0,
>           DEFAULT( membership_credits),
>           membership_credits) AS membership_credits,
>       IF(COUNT(user_id) = 0,
>           DEFAULT( product_credits),
>           product_credits) AS product_credits FROM
>       (SELECT 1) AS dummy LEFT JOIN
>       Users ON TRUE

Answer (score -1):

Use the below query :

SELECT 
    IF(COUNT(user_id) = 0,
        DEFAULT( membership_credits),
        membership_credits) AS membership_credits,
    IF(COUNT(user_id) = 0,
        DEFAULT( product_credits),
        product_credits) AS product_credits
FROM
    (SELECT 1) AS dummy
LEFT JOIN
    Users ON TRUE

Comment: Not an answer to the question

Comment: I know the table is empty. What I was looking for was a way for the query to work in the presented conditions.