# MySQL INSERT INTO ... SELECT or default value

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert

I'm working on following query:

```
INSERT INTO a (id, value) VALUES (_id, (SELECT value FROM b WHERE b.id = _id));
```

Table a: id, value (has a default value)

Table b: id, value

Table b does not contain all requested values. So the SELECT query sometimes returns 0 rows. In this case it should use the default value of a.value.

Is this somehow possible?

**Edit:**

Solution for empty columns in comments of the post marked as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query would work. First the max(value) is looked up from table b for _id. It would be either NULL or equal to b.value. If it is NULL (checked using the COALESCE function), then the default value of the value column of table a is set as the value.

The default value of the value column of table a is accessed using the DEFAULT function (please refer Reference 1).

```
INSERT INTO a
SELECT 
  _id, 
  COALESCE(max(value), (SELECT DEFAULT(value) FROM a LIMIT 1)) value
FROM b
WHERE id = _id;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d495/1)</kbd>

**Reference**:

1. [How to SELECT DEFAULT value of a field on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266771/how-to-select-default-value-of-a-field)

Comment: I've tested it, but the solution is not perfect. This works iff there are more than one row in table a. But unfortunately this is not always the case. :/ Is there a possibility to make a query which also works if the table is empty?

Comment: The theoretical solution in your reference does not work either (the solution itself): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6fd73/1

Comment: Are you abke to get the default value with this query? SELECT COLUMN_DEFAULT FROM information_schema.columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'a' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'id';

Comment: yes this works! It's too bad that MySQL doesn't provide a function to get the default value of a (empty) column.

Answer (score 3):

you can wrap the value in `coalesce(max(value), default_value)`

```
INSERT INTO a (id, value) 
VALUES (_id, (SELECT coalesce(max(value), default_value)) FROM b WHERE b.id = _id));
```

Comment: If you only need set a custom value, use `COALESCE(NULL,"yourdefaultvalue")`

Answer (score 0):

If MySQL follows other RDBMS behaviour, the default is only picked up when you don't even specify the field.  This means that you need two different INSERT statements:

```
IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM b WHERE id = _id)) THEN
  INSERT INTO a (id, value) SELECT _id, value FROM b WHERE id = _id;
ELSE
  INSERT INTO a (id) SELECT _id;
END IF;
```

Or, possibly, something like this...

```
INSERT INTO a (id, value) SELECT _id, value FROM b WHERE id = _id;

IF ((SELECT ROW_COUNT()) = 0) THEN
  INSERT INTO a (id) SELECT _id;
END IF;
```

Please note, this is conceptual.  I've looked up the syntax for you, but I haven't tested it on MySQL.

Comment: both examples dont work. /*There is no EXISTS-function like in the first example and */the second one doesn't work because the INSERT query is still successful even if the SELECT query return 0 rows.